# Why does 64 bit casting enum related CreateDelegate fail?

Tags: c#, delegates, enums

In the below code snippet, the call to CreateDelegate with the 64-bit enum throws an ArgumentException "Error binding to target method". Yet the 32-bit enum works fine.

Could someone tell me why?

```
class Test
{
    public static void DoIt()
    {
        Func<int, int> f32 = i => i;
        var d32 = (Func<int, E32>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, E32>), f32.Method);

        Func<long, long> f64 = i => i;
        var d64 = (Func<long, E64>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<long, E64>), f64.Method);
    }
}

enum E32 { };
enum E64 { };
```

(For some context on this weird code, it's inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026609/14582)

Is there something special about 64-bit enums that makes this fail, perhaps an unimplemented code path in binding argument matching code? Or is it a quirk that 32-bit enum works in this way?

Comment: bah, I just realized I'm missing the ": long" on the E64. Works fine after all. Closing this.

Comment: Both your enums are 32 bit. use `E64:long` to create a 64 bit enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base type of `E64` is `int` not `long` which makes it incompatible with a function that has a return type of `long`.  The f32 version works because `E32` and `int` are compatible types.

You can fix this sample by having `E64` set it's base type to `long`

```
enum E64 : long {}
```

Comment: Yeah I realized this 5 seconds after posting. Oops.

Comment: @ScottBilas sometimes the easiest way to figure out the answer is to explain the problem to someone else :).

Comment: Totally. :) The bar is very high here too. Really need to make sure my premises are correct before hitting the almighty submit button. 99% is not good enough!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a 64-bit enum.
You need to add `: long`.