# ArgumentException: method return type is incompatible (Mono)

Tags: c#, exception, delegates, mono, argumentexception

The following source works as expected when using .NET inside Visual Studio, but it throws the aforementioned exception when using the Mono framework:

```
class Foo<TEnum> where TEnum : struct {

    private static Func<int, int> Identity = (value) => value;
    private static Func<int, TEnum> IntToEnum = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, TEnum>), Identity.Method) as Func<int, TEnum>;
    private static Func<TEnum, int> EnumToInt = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TEnum, int>), Identity.Method) as Func<TEnum, int>;

    public static bool EnumEquals(TEnum lhs, TEnum rhs) {
        return EnumToInt(lhs) == EnumToInt(rhs);
    }

}

Foo<SomeEnum>.EnumEquals(SomeEnum.A, SomeEnum.B);
```

Is there a workaround to this which, like above, avoids boxing/unboxing values?

I am stuck with the Mono implementation which resides inside Unity :/

**The Exception**

```
ArgumentException: method return type is incompatible
System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Delegate.cs:190)
System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Delegate.cs:291)
System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Delegate.cs:295)
Foo`1[SomeEnum]..cctor ()
...
```

Comment: I am uncertain as to how reliable this proposal is, but it *seems* to work (http://hastebin.com/ahoxoleyed.cs). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I do not entirely understand the following, but it *seems* to work for both .NET and Mono and it doesn't allocate. Any comments on caveats or reliability would be appreciated!

This was adapted [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189144/c-sharp-non-boxing-conversion-of-generic-enum-to-int#answer-23391746) (the only difference is that `Expression.Parameter` requires a second parameter to please the version of Mono which is used by Unity.

```
internal static class CastTo<T> {
    public static T From<S>(S s) {
        return Cache<S>.caster(s);
    }

    static class Cache<S> {
        internal static readonly Func<S, T> caster = Get();

        static Func<S, T> Get() {
            var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(S), "S");
            var c = Expression.ConvertChecked(p, typeof(T));
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<S, T>>(c, p).Compile();
        }
    }
}
```

Which can then be used as follows:

```
public enum Example {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

long example = CastTo<long>.From<Example>(Example.B);
```