# dictionary enum key performance

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, enums, mono

I have a concern about generic dictionaries using enums for keys.

As stated at the below page, using enums for keys will allocate memory:
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/07/02/twin-paths-to-garbage-collector-nirvana.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20190216001802/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2007/07/02/twin-paths-to-garbage-collector-nirvana/)

I've tested and confirmed the behavior, and it's causing problems in my project. For readability, I believe using enums for keys is very useful, and the optimal solution for me would be to write write a class implementing `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, which would use integers for keys internally. The reason is I don't want to change all my existing dictionaries to use integers for keys, and do implicit casting. This would be best performance wise, but it will give me lot of work initially and it will reduce the readability.

So I've tried a couple of approaches, including using `GetHashCode` (which unfortunately allocates memory) to build an internal `Dictionary<int, TValue>`.

So, to wrap it up in one question; can anyone think of a solution that I can use to keep the readability of `Dictionary<SomeEnum, TValue>`, while having the perfomance of a `Dictionary<int, TValue>`?

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like premature-optimization to me. What kind of application are you developing?

Comment: I can't imagine how you could possibly do any better than an `enum` here.  It will have identical performance implications to using an integer (assuming it's backed by one, which it will be by default).

Comment: Its mobile gaming, and it's causing lag spikes due to garbage collection.

Comment: "It will have identical performance implications to using an integer". That is not true unfortunately, I've tested and confirmed. Using enums allocates memory when getting items from the dictionary.

Comment: His statement about enums sounds like something you would say about Java, not .Net. .Net generics does not work like Java's.

Comment: @MagnusAndersson An enum is just syntactic sugar for using an integer.  It doesn't surprise me in the least that some amount of memory is used in getting the key from a dictionary.  You're going to use some amount of memory to do anything, ever.  Computers run on memory.  You're simply not going to get better than what you have.  If you do in fact have a measurable problem in your application, it's almost certainly not because you choose to use an `Enum` and not an integer as a key for a dictionary.

Comment: " GetHashCode (which unfortunately allocates memory) " - can you eloborate here?  How does `GetHashCode` on an enum allocate memory?

Comment: @DStanley Well there's the stack frame for the method, and any locals (implicit and explicit) that it uses, to which I'm sure there are at least a few.

Comment: @Magnus, please show a simple program that demonstrates your contention that enums perform differently than ints.

Comment: @Servy Again, I've tested and confirmed that having an int for the key allocates 0 memory, while having an integer based enum allocates.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this is using the Mono framework, might be of interest...

Comment: @Magnus, and *how* are you determining that "an int allocates 0 memory"?  Please show us code that demonstrates this.

Comment: I'm using the internal memory profiler of the game engine we're using, which states that DefaultComparer.Equals() and DefaultComparer.GetHashCode() are both being called and allocates memory while getting an item from en enum-based dictionary.

Comment: The corresponding call using an int-based dictionary reports 0 memory footprint. I'm not the one to guarantee the profiler is right, but I have no reason do doubt it.

Comment: Show us your enum, your enum could be of type int or uint. So just cast your enum to int/uint on insert or access to your dictionary. problem solved.

Comment: @MagnusAndersson Considering an `Enum` is nothing but compile time wrapping for an integer, you have *every* reason to doubt it.  The issue is almost certainly with your testing, rather than with the code.

Comment: The problem with creating your own `IDictionary<S,T>` where `S` is an enum type is that it's kind of difficult to [restrict a generic type to a enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum). If you have only a handful of enums to worry about, it might be worth your time to create a (bunch of) `MyEnumDictionary<T> : IDictionary<MyEnum,T>` for each enum.

Comment: @MattBurland Yes, the fact that you're using Mono is extremely relevant. Looking at [`Comparer.cs`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Comparer.cs), its implementation of `Comparer<T>.Default` is quite a poor one.

Comment: @hvd Sorry for not stating that at the beginning.

Comment: @Servy The lag spike caused by the garbage collection (caused by the dictionary look-up) is visible to the naked eye, and goes away when using int keys. Not sure how much more obvious it can be for me here, sorry you dont trust my judgement saying it's from that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is **boxing**. It's an act of turning value type into object, which might, or might not be unnecessary.

The way `Dictionary`compares keys, is essentially, that it will use `EqualComparer<T>.Default`, and call `GetHashCode()` to find correct bucket, and `Equals` to compare if there's any value in the bucket that is equal tot he one we're looking for.

The good thing is this: .NET framework has good optimizations, which avoid boxing in the case of `"Enum integers"`. See [CreateComparer()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs). It's highly unlikely that you will see any difference here, between integers and enums, as keys.

To note here: this is not an easy act, in fact, if you dig in deep, you'll come to conclusion that quarter of this battle is implemented through CLR "hacks". As seen here:

```
   static internal int UnsafeEnumCast<T>(T val) where T : struct    
    {
        // should be return (int) val; but C# does not allow, runtime 
        // does this magically
        // See getILIntrinsicImplementation for how this happens.  
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
```

It could be definitely easier if generics had Enum constraint, and perhaps even something a long of the lines  `UnsafeEnumCast<T>(T val) where T : Enum->Integer`, but well... they don't.

You might be wondering, what exactly is going on in getILIntrinsicImplementation for that `EnumCast`? I wonder too. Not exactly sure as of this right moment how to check it. It's replaced on run-time with specific IL code I believe?!

## MONO

Now, answer to your question: yes you're right. `Enum` as a key on Mono, will be  slower in a tight loop. It's because Mono does boxing on Enums, as far I can see. You can check out [EnumIntEqualityComparer](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/EqualityComparer.cs), as you can see, it calls `Array.UnsafeMov` that basically casts a type of `T` into integer, through boxing: `(int)(object) instance;`. That's the "classical" limitation of generics, and there is no nice solution for this problem.

### Solution 1

Implement an `EqualityComparer<MyEnum>` for your concrete Enum. This will avoid all the casting.

```
public struct MyEnumCOmparer : IEqualityComparer<MyEnum>
{
    public bool Equals(MyEnum x, MyEnum y)
    {
        return x == y;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyEnum obj)
    {
        // you need to do some thinking here,
        return (int)obj;
    }
}
```

All you need to do then, is pass it to your `Dictionary`:

`new Dictionary<MyEnum, int>(new MyEnumComparer());`

It works, it gives you the same performance as it is with integers, and avoids boxing issues. The problem is though, this is not generic and writing this for each `Enum` can feel stupid.

### Solution 2

Writing a generic `Enum` comparer, and using few tricks that avoids unboxing. I wrote this with a little help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189144/c-sharp-non-boxing-conversion-of-generic-enum-to-int),

```
// todo; check if your TEnum is enum && typeCode == TypeCode.Int
struct FastEnumIntEqualityComparer<TEnum> : IEqualityComparer<TEnum> 
    where TEnum : struct
{
    static class BoxAvoidance
    {
        static readonly Func<TEnum, int> _wrapper;

        public static int ToInt(TEnum enu)
        {
            return _wrapper(enu);
        }

        static BoxAvoidance()
        {
            var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEnum), null);
            var c = Expression.ConvertChecked(p, typeof(int));

            _wrapper = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEnum, int>>(c, p).Compile();
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(TEnum firstEnum, TEnum secondEnum)
    {
        return BoxAvoidance.ToInt(firstEnum) == 
            BoxAvoidance.ToInt(secondEnum);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TEnum firstEnum)
    {
        return BoxAvoidance.ToInt(firstEnum);
    }
}
```

### Solution 3

Now, there's a little problem with the solution#2, as `Expression.Compile()` is not that famous on iOS(no runtime code generation), and some mono versions don't have ?? `Expression.Compile` ?? (not sure).

You can write simple IL code that will take care of the enum conversion, and compile it.

```
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .ver 0:0:0:0
}
.assembly 'enum2int'
{
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver  0:0:0:0
}

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit EnumInt32ToInt
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig static int32  Convert<valuetype 
        .ctor ([mscorlib]System.ValueType) TEnum>(!!TEnum 'value') cil managed
    {
      .maxstack  8
      IL_0000:  ldarg.0
      IL_000b:  ret
    }
}
```

In order to compile it into an assembly, you have to call:

`ilasm enum2int.il /dll` where enum2int.il is the text file containing IL.

You can now reference the given assembly(`enum2int.dll`) and call the static method, as such:

```
struct FastEnumIntEqualityComparer<TEnum> : IEqualityComparer<TEnum> 
    where TEnum : struct
{
    int ToInt(TEnum en)
    {
        return EnumInt32ToInt.Convert(en);
    }

    public bool Equals(TEnum firstEnum, TEnum secondEnum)
    {
        return ToInt(firstEnum) == ToInt(secondEnum);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TEnum firstEnum)
    {
        return ToInt(firstEnum);
    }
}
```

It might seem to be killer code, but it avoids boxing, and it should give you better berformance on `Mono`.

Comment: Thanks, nice suggestion. I guess there is no way of having this done generally, without having to write a comparer for each enum?

Comment: I updated the post. If mono does not support that, you can write one generic class, and use that, instead of writing class for each enum: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs#0f1674ddefef561e#references

Comment: findings after testing your suggestion is that memory footprint is reduced by 2/3, but to get it to 0 I need to cast the obj to an integer in GetHashCode(MyEnum obj) before getting the hash code. unfortunately that removes the option of writing a generic comparer, as we cant constrain to enums of type int. any ideas?

Comment: I don't have benchmark capabilities available right now, but I believe the solution#2 is as close as you can possibly get.

Comment: Testing of solution 2 results in an "ArgumentException: method return type is incompatible" from the CreateDelegate call. I'm still digesting whats going on in this comparer, you have an idea how to fix the issue? The enum I'm using is definitely of integer type, so I dont know why I get the error.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. The `CreateDelegate` seemed fishy to me, although it worked. I've updated the solution#2, which uses another method, and which imo is better. Let me know how it goes, and I might even try to get this change integrated to Mono :p

Comment: As is, solution #2 doesn't compile in my Mono version. I added an empty string to Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEnum)) to work around it, and tested. 0 memory allocation!

Comment: The #2 solution above works very well using Monotouch for Android and PC standalone. However, due to limitations on iOS (no JIT compile) it does not run on iOS. Can anyone think of a similar solution that would actually work on iOS?

Comment: @MagnusAndersson: Mono has what is known as AOT, but it currently doesn't work with generics, that's why it fails. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/aot/  To actually create a solution that should work theoretically on all the platforms, is to write code in IL and use ilasm. See solution#3

Comment: Solution #3 did work on all platforms, extremely useful.

Comment: Why does the .NET source need to do those unsafe casts in its comparers (UnsafeEnumCast(x))  if we can just do x == y for our custom comparer?

Comment: Also the link to the mono source is dead - it shows 404 page on github.

Comment: .Net core also handles this. See [ComparerHelpers.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/84092471c678da00bb59d86fb5fcd0890a524472/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/ComparerHelpers.cs#L91).

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa I have upvoted this answer for general reasons, but I do not see the reason for struct implementations of IEqualityComparer as it is handed to dictionary in constructor and boxing has to happen...

Comment: @ipavlu boxing can happen in constructor, that is fine. The idea of my post is that in order to speed up things, boxing should not happen when .Equals() method is called by dictionary internally. It does not happen on the custom struct.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa Exactly the reason, why I upvoted as the primary part of the answer is correct. I just do not agree with this implicit boxing of IEqualityComparer for Dictionary constructor. Making IEqualityComparer struct in the first place brings no advantage, just complications and hides something to the developer. Why the develper should spent time thinking that it was boxed and as result he/she can

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa Damned edit rules, 5min timer took over:).
What if you make a high number of these dictionaries? If it is a class, you can not miss its construction. If it is a struct, you can easily miss it. Making things explicit is an easy way of life, especially when the code must be read by other developers and when the extravagant choice brings only confusion and possible problems during refactoring or development in large teams...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem a while back and ended up incorporating it into a library I wrote of generic enum extension and helper methods (it's written in C++/CLI (compiled AnyCPU) because C# doesn't allow creation of type constraints for enum types).  It's available under the Apache 2.0 license on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DiagonacticEnumsExtensions) and [GitHub](https://github.com/Diagonactic/Enums.Delegates.CppCLI)

You can implement it in a `Dictionary` by grabbing the `IEqualityComparer` from the static `Enums` type in the library:

```
var equalityComparer = Enums.EqualityComparer<MyEnum>();
var dictionary = new Dictionary<MyEnum, MyValueType>(equalityComparer);
```

The values are handled without boxing, using a technique similar to the `UnsafeEnumCast` mentioned in one of the answers already provided (covered to death in tests since it is *unsafe*).  As a result, it's very fast (since that would be the only point of replacing an equality comparer in this case).  A benchmarking app is included as well as recent results generated from my build PC.

Answer (score 1):

Enums as dictionary keys now have the same or better performance as `int` dictionary keys. I measured this using NUnit:

```
public class EnumSpeedTest
{
    const int Iterations = 10_000_000;

    [Test]
    public void WasteTimeInt()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            dict[i] = i;
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            sum += dict[i];
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }

    enum Enum { Zero = 0, One = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3 }

    [Test]
    public void WasteTimeEnum()
    {
        Dictionary<Enum, int> dict = new Dictionary<Enum, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            dict[(Enum)i] = i;
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            sum += dict[(Enum)i];
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

The time taken by these two tests on my Ryzen 5 PC in a .NET 5.0 Release build is consistently around 300ms, and the enum version is slightly faster on most runs.

Answer (score 0):

In later .net versions (tested for .NET7), performance is the same as using `int` as key.
Using an `IEqualityComparer` struct as the Dictionary's constructor argument even make performance worse.
For reference, here is some code that shows some alternatives and corresponding performances. The code uses *BenchmarkDotNet* framwork.

```
public enum MyEnum { Zero = 0, One = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3, Four = 4, Five = 5, Six = 6, Seven = 7, Eight = 8, Nine = 9, Ten = 10 }

public class DictionaryBenchmark
{
    const int count = 100;


    [Benchmark]
    public void Int()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        dict[0] = 0;
        dict[1] = 1;
        dict[2] = 2;
        dict[3] = 3;
        dict[4] = 4;
        dict[5] = 5;
        dict[6] = 6;
        dict[7] = 7;
        dict[8] = 8;
        dict[9] = 9;
        dict[10] = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            long sum = dict[0] +
                       dict[1] +
                       dict[2] +
                       dict[3] +
                       dict[4] +
                       dict[5] +
                       dict[6] +
                       dict[7] +
                       dict[8] +
                       dict[9] +
                       dict[10];
        }

    }


    [Benchmark]
    public void Enum()
    {
        Dictionary<MyEnum, int> dict = new Dictionary<MyEnum, int>();

        dict[MyEnum.Zero] = 0;
        dict[MyEnum.One] = 1;
        dict[MyEnum.Two] = 2;
        dict[MyEnum.Three] = 3;
        dict[MyEnum.Four] = 4;
        dict[MyEnum.Five] = 5;
        dict[MyEnum.Six] = 6;
        dict[MyEnum.Seven] = 7;
        dict[MyEnum.Eight] = 8;
        dict[MyEnum.Nine] = 9;
        dict[MyEnum.Ten] = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            long sum = dict[MyEnum.Zero] +
                       dict[MyEnum.One] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Two] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Three] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Four] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Five] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Six] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Seven] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Eight] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Nine] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Ten];
        }

    }

    struct MyEnumComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyEnum>
    {
        public bool Equals(MyEnum x, MyEnum y)
        {
            return x == y;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(MyEnum obj)
        {
            return (int)obj;
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void EqualityComparer()
    {
        Dictionary<MyEnum, int> dict = new Dictionary<MyEnum, int>(new MyEnumComparer());

        dict[MyEnum.Zero] = 0;
        dict[MyEnum.One] = 1;
        dict[MyEnum.Two] = 2;
        dict[MyEnum.Three] = 3;
        dict[MyEnum.Four] = 4;
        dict[MyEnum.Five] = 5;
        dict[MyEnum.Six] = 6;
        dict[MyEnum.Seven] = 7;
        dict[MyEnum.Eight] = 8;
        dict[MyEnum.Nine] = 9;
        dict[MyEnum.Ten] = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            long sum = dict[MyEnum.Zero] +
                       dict[MyEnum.One] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Two] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Three] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Four] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Five] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Six] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Seven] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Eight] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Nine] +
                       dict[MyEnum.Ten];
        }
    }
    [Benchmark]
    public void Switch()
    {
        // dummy code to make benchmark more fair
        Dictionary<MyEnum, int> dict = new Dictionary<MyEnum, int>();

        dict[MyEnum.Zero] = 0;
        dict[MyEnum.One] = 1;
        dict[MyEnum.Two] = 2;
        dict[MyEnum.Three] = 3;
        dict[MyEnum.Four] = 4;
        dict[MyEnum.Five] = 5;
        dict[MyEnum.Six] = 6;
        dict[MyEnum.Seven] = 7;
        dict[MyEnum.Eight] = 8;
        dict[MyEnum.Nine] = 9;
        dict[MyEnum.Ten] = 10;
        // end of dummy code

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            long sum = GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum.Zero) +
                       GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum.One) +
                       GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum.Two) +
                       GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum.Three) +
                       GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum.Four) +
                       GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum.Five) +
                       GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum.Six) +
                       GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum.Seven) +
                       GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum.Eight) +
                       GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum.Nine) +
                       GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum.Ten);
        }

    }

    private int GetIntFromEnum(MyEnum fromMyEnum)
    {
        return fromMyEnum switch
        {
            MyEnum.Zero => 0,
            MyEnum.One => 1,
            MyEnum.Two => 2,
            MyEnum.Three => 3,
            MyEnum.Four => 4,
            MyEnum.Five => 5,
            MyEnum.Six => 6,
            MyEnum.Seven => 7,
            MyEnum.Eight => 8,
            MyEnum.Nine => 9,
            MyEnum.Ten => 10,
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(fromMyEnum), fromMyEnum, null)
        };
    }
    

    [Benchmark]
    public void String()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        dict["Zero"] = 0;
        dict["One"] = 1;
        dict["Two"] = 2;
        dict["Three"] = 3;
        dict["Four"] = 4;
        dict["Five"] = 5;
        dict["Six"] = 6;
        dict["Seven"] = 7;
        dict["Eight"] = 8;
        dict["Nine"] = 9;
        dict["Ten"] = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            long sum = dict["Zero"] +
                       dict["One"] +
                       dict["Two"] +
                       dict["Three"] +
                       dict["Four"] +
                       dict["Five"] +
                       dict["Six"] +
                       dict["Seven"] +
                       dict["Eight"] +
                       dict["Nine"] +
                       dict["Ten"];
        }
    }
}
```

**Benchmarking results**:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Int | 2.385 us | 0.0443 us | 0.0455 us |
| Enum | 2.502 us | 0.0415 us | 0.0388 us |
| EqualityComparer | 7.701 us | 0.0916 us | 0.0765 us |
| Switch | 2.072 us | 0.0271 us | 0.0253 us |
| String | 6.765 us | 0.1316 us | 0.1293 us |